# Is there an easy way to get the percentage of successful reads of last x minutes?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, percentage

I have a setup with a Beaglebone Black which communicates over I²C with his slaves every second and reads data from them. Sometimes the I²C readout fails though, and I want to get statistics about these fails.

I would like to implement an algorithm which displays the percentage of successful communications of the last 5 minutes (up to 24 hours) and updates that value constantly. If I would implement that 'normally' with an array where I store success/no success of every second, that would mean a lot of wasted RAM/CPU load for a minor feature (especially if I would like to see the statistics of the last 24 hours).

Does someone know a good way to do that, or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is?  How would this feature use a lot of RAM or CPU?  You need only keep success and fail counts?

Comment: @MartinJames Because one would have to keep track of every read's status and its timestamp, I guess

Comment: @Eregrith: do the math yourself or see my answer. Totally negligible.

Comment: On most platforms the memory is negligible but perhaps not on all.

Comment: @Simon: it's not "any" platform; OP says it's a beaglebone black, which has 512MB of RAM, not some 8 bit microcontroller :)

Comment: As there might be a lot of slaves I just wanted to implement the feature to be future-proof. Using a low-pass filter sounds reasonable and it's not really about the exact value, but rather to determine a trend of which devices are failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just implement a low-pass filter? For every successfull transfer, you push in a 1, for every failed one a 0; the result is a number between 0 and 1. Assuming that your transfers happen periodically, this works well -- and you just have to adjust the cutoff frequency of that filter to your desired "averaging duration".

However, I can't follow your RAM argument: assuming you store one byte representing success or failure per transfer, which you say happens every second, you end up with 86400B per day -- 85KB/day is really negligible.

**EDIT** Cutoff frequency is something from signal theory and describes the highest or lowest frequency that passes a low or high pass filter.

Implementing a low-pass filter is trivial; something like (pseudocode):

```
new_val = 1 //init with no failed transfers
alpha = 0.001
while(true):
    old_val=new_val
    success=do_transfer_and_return_1_on_success_or_0_on_failure()
    new_val = alpha * success + (1-alpha) * old_val
```

That's a single-tap IIR (infinite impulse response) filter; single tap because there's only one alpha and thus, only one number that is stored as state.

**EDIT2**: the value of `alpha` defines the behaviour of this filter.

**EDIT3**: you can use a filter design tool to give you the right `alpha`; just set your low pass filter's cutoff frequency to something like 0.5/integrationLengthInSamples, select an order of 0 for the IIR and use an elliptic design method (most tools default to butterworth, but 0 order butterworths don't do a thing).

I'd use scipy and convert the resulting `(b,a)` tuple (`a` will be 1, here) to the correct form for this feedback form.

Comment: How and what would you adjust in order to get data only from last n minutes without storing the events timestamps?

Comment: Oh I see, I get what you mean by *push a 0 or a 1*

Comment: @Eregrith: true, but there's theory that allows you to estimate the error for a given sampling time jitter. I personally believe this to be negligible in this case, but I'm too lazy to get out the proper math.

Comment: Looking at your edit it seems if the first transfer returns 0, the value of new_val will be `0.999` at second 1, but it should be 0. If the transfers keep failing the value of `new_val` will decrease ever so slowly. Isn't that incorrect?

Comment: @Eregrith: first 0, second 1: `output[0] = 0.001 * 0 + 0.999 * 1 = 0.999`,  `output[1] = 0.001 * 1  + 0.999*0.999 ~= 0.001 + 0.99801 = 0.99901`

Comment: @Eregrith: it shouldn't be 0 ! that would defy the purpose of the filter, which is giving you an approximate long-term average of the input sequence as output sequence

Comment: OP wants the ratio of success/fails of reads, if the function keeps returning 0 it *should* be 0, shouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79953/discussion-between-eregrith-and-marcus-muller-).

Comment: @Eregrith: you'll find that after a series of 0, the value approaches 0; however as OP wants a 5 min average, it takes some time to reach 0. In fact, 0.001 is a *very* small alpha, an 0.2 might be a better choice. You will need to use the IIR design tool of your choice to find a suitable alpha!

Comment: Five minutes of nonstop zeroes gives 0.7407068... how is that close to 0 ?

Comment: @Eregrith: although this discussion goes on in the chat: with an alpha of 0.001, yes. if you increase alpha, the "averaging" duration goes down, just to archive this for the afterworld :)

Comment: Thanks for your input and also suggesting some helpful tools. I will definitely try how this solution works in my application and report back.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** In light of the comment by the OP 'determine a trend of which devices are failing' I would recommend the geometric average that Marcus Müller ꕺꕺ put forward.

**ACCURATE METHOD**

The method below is aimed at obtaining 'well defined' statistics for performance over time that are also useful for 'after the fact' analysis.
Notice that geometric average has a 'look back' over recent messages rather than fixed time period.

Maintain a rolling array of 24*60/5 = 288 'prior success rates' (SR[i] with i=-1, -2,...,-288) each representing a 5 minute interval in the preceding 24 hours.

That will consume about 2.5K if the elements are 64-bit doubles.

To 'effect' constant updating use an Estimated 'Current' Success Rate as follows:

ECSR = (t*S/M+(300-t)*SR[-1])/300

Where S and M are the count of errors and messages in the current (partially complete period. SR[-1] is the previous (now complete) bucket.

t is the number of seconds expired of the current bucket.

NB: When you start up you need to use 300*S/M/t.

In essence the approximation assumes the error rate was steady over the preceding 5 - 10 minutes.

To 'effect' a 24 hour look back you can either 'shuffle' the data down (by copy or `memcpy()`) at the end of each 5 minute interval or implement a 'circular array by keeping track of the current bucket index'.

**NB:** For many management/diagnostic purposes intervals of 15 minutes are often entirely adequate. You might want to make the 'grain' configurable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really appreciate all the help